# How to get surely all data from side input without lose half data?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

We have a Dataflow pipeline, everytime the side input refresh we have seen the table who cache data and during the refresh there are not all data inside. Obviously the rest of pipeline continue to work with raw data. Is there a possibility to fix it?

to not lose the data

this is the script

```java
PCollection<TableRow> sideInput=pipeline
  .apply(GenerateSequence.from(0).withRate(1, Duration.standardSeconds(180)))
  .apply(Window.<Long>into(new GlobalWindows()) .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane())).discardingFiredPanes())
  .apply("REFRESH-SIDEINPUT", ParDo.of(new SideInputQuery(psToBqOptions.getBQProjectSideInput()))); 

PCollectionView<Map<String, String>> sideInputView = sideInput
  .apply("To map", ParDo.of(new TableRowToMap()))
  .apply(View.<String, String>asMap());


public class SideInputQuery extends DoFn<Long, TableRow> {
    
    private ValueProvider<String> ProjectIdRefresh;
    PubSubToBqOptions psToBqOptions;
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SideInputQuery.class);
    
    public SideInputQuery(ValueProvider<String> ProjectIdRefresh)
    {
        this.ProjectIdRefresh = ProjectIdRefresh;
    }
    
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
        
        BigQuery bigQuery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
        
        QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder("SELECT distinct storeId as storeID_rebuild, "
                        + "cast(C.code as INT64) as storeId  "
                        + "FROM `" + ProjectIdRefresh.get() + ".{dataser}.{table}` s INNER JOIN UNNEST(s.{field}) as C on (C.type='type') "
                        + "where 1=1 ").build();

        TableResult results = bigQuery.query(queryConfig);
        System.out.println(results);
        for(FieldValueList fvl:results.iterateAll())
        {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();
            tr.set("storeId", fvl.get("storeId").getNumericValue());
            tr.set("storeID_rebuild", fvl.get("storeID_rebuild").getNumericValue());
            LOG.info("storeId" + fvl.get("storeId").getNumericValue() + " storeID_rebuild" + fvl.get("storeID_rebuild").getNumericValue());
            c.output(tr);           
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a code snippet with the side input please ?

Comment: Is it possible to share  your code?

Comment: @MazlumTosun 
Hi both, this is the code snippet
'PCollection<TableRow> sideInput=pipeline.apply(GenerateSequence.from(0).withRate(1, Duration.standardSeconds(180))).apply(Window.<Long>into(new GlobalWindows())          .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane())).discardingFiredPanes()).apply("REFRESH-SIDEINPUT", ParDo.of(new SideInputQuery(psToBqOptions.getBQProjectSideInput()))); PCollectionView<Map<String, String>> sideInputView = sideInput.apply("To map", ParDo.of(new TableRowToMap())).apply(View.<String, String>asMap());

Comment: @kiranmathew please see my comment

Comment: @AntonioSilvestri Can you confirm whether the code is working as intended or not and check what is written inside `new SideInputQuery()`?Is it possible to share (SideInputQuery)code?

Comment: Hi all, script updated. @kiranmathew